# normalizing json lines in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, jsonlines

I have a json line file, where each line has some structure which I am trying to (mostly) flatten, thus:

```
with open("/home/igor/data/feed.jsonl") as json_file:
    thelist2 = []
    for line in json_file:
        thelist2.append(json_normalize(json.loads(line)))
```

Followed by `pd.concat(thelist2)` The semantics of the above is correct, but what is not so good is that this is horrifically slow, while running the above without `json_normalize` is quite speedy (but does the wrong thing). Is there a way to normalize the dataframe after the fact, or some other speedier scheme?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezzrael I will try to scare some data up...